# Stanford Parser models

Tags: stanford-nlp

Stanford CoreNLP contains several models for parsing English sentences.

- englishSR
- english_SD
- english_UD (default for depparse annotator)
- englishRNN
- englishFactored
- englishPCFG (default for parse annotator)
- englishPCFG.caseless
- wsjRNN
- wsjFactored
- wsjPCFG

There are some comparisons in following papers:

- http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-dependencies.shtml#English
- http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/lrecstanforddeps_final_final.pdf
- http://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/SocherBauerManningNg_ACL2013.pdf
- http://cs.stanford.edu/people/danqi/papers/emnlp2014.pdf

I couldn't find full description and comparison for all models.
Does it exist anywhere? If not I think it is worth to create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't give a full list (maybe Chris will chime in?), but my understanding is that these models are:

- `englishSR`: The shift reduce model trained on various standard treebanks, and some of Stanford's hand-annotated data. This is the fastest and most accurate model we have, but the model is huge to load.
- `english_SD`: The NN Dependency Parser model for Stanford Dependencies. Deprecated in favor of `english_UD` -- the Universal Dependencies model.
- `english_UD`: The NN Dependency Parser model for Universal Dependencies. This is the fastest and most accurate way to get dependency trees, but it won't give you constituency parses.
- `englishRNN`: The hybrid PCFG + Neural constituency parser model. More accurate than any of the constituency parsers other than the shift-reduce model, but also noticeably slower.
- `englishFactored`: Not 100% sure what this is, but my impression is that both accuracy and speed-wise it's between `englishPCFG` and `englishRNN`.
- `englishPCFG`: A regular old PCFG model for constituency parsing. Fast to load, and faster than any of the constituency models other than the shift-reduce model, but also kind of mediocre accuracy by modern standards. Nonetheless, a good default.
- `englishPCFG.caseless`: A caseless version of the PCFG model.

I assume the `wsj*` models are there to reproduce numbers in papers (trained on the proper WSJ splits), but again I'm not 100% sure what they are.

To help chose the right model based on speed, accuracy, and the base memory used by the model:

- Fast: 10x, accurate, high-memory: englishSR
- Medium: 1x, ok accuracy, low-memory: englishPCFG
- Slow: ~0.25x, accurate, low-memory: englishRNN
- Fast: 100x, accurate, low-memory, dependency parses only: english_UD